# Job title changed to Lead xxx. Should I create a new job position on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin, title

I have for a long time already had influence outside my work team. My title was now changed from xxx to Lead xxx to better reflect the scope of my work and give a little more authority in the customer interface. The job description was not changed since the content doesn't really change.

Should I create a new job position on LinkedIn for this, even though the description of the new position would be about the same as for the current position? Or should I merely change the title of the current position?

Comment: It's a step up in role and responsibility. Why not?

Comment: Short answer: add the leadership you have accomplished.

Comment: Yes, you should.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would definitely do it.

It looks like an advancement, which is always positive. In any case, it shows that you are progressing in your company.

Rewrite the old job description by removing references to the fact that your influence was greater than your role in the team. Move what you removed to the lead role description.

Comment: Plus the change, while not accompanied by a new job description, is an acknowledgement of natural growth that comes with experience at a job. You are not the same worker as when you started, and if your company is formally and official recognizing it, it is completely honest to update profiles and resumes to reflect that, as well.  ("you" refers to OP).